# How to calculate distance between two set of coordinates in meter?

Tags: matlab, mapping, latitude-longitude

My question is: how to calculate distance between two sets of coordinates in meter by matlab?

I have two coordinates like N1 32.22 E1 15.09 and N2 32.45 E2 15.55, by command `[k b] = distance(N1, E1, N2, E2)` it gives the great circle arcs and the azimuths, but I need the distance in meters or Km.

Comment: This question has been asked, and answered, many times here on SO.  Beyond that, the Internet will overwhelm you with resources for satisfying your requirements.  I suggest you do some research, return when (and if) you have a program that you need help finishing.

Comment: Convert to UTM and do it cartesic, if they are near enough (<1000km or so). Otherwise, look up Great Circles. Ask on [GIS.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can form geodetic data in terms of 'kilometer' or 'meter' of unit using [`geodetic2ned()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/geodetic2ned.html) function but this needs `Mapping Toolbox`.

Now check the code below:

```
pos1     = [32.22, 15.09];
pos2     = [32.45, 15.55];
h        = 0;                                 % // altitude                         
SPHEROID = referenceEllipsoid('wgs84', 'km'); % // Reference ellipsoid. You can enter 'km' or 'm'    
[N, E]   = geodetic2ned(pos1(1), pos1(2), h, pos2(1), pos2(2), h, SPHEROID);
distance = norm([N, E]);
```

This results distance as `50.2598` kilometer.

Comment: @mirabilos - Of course there will be an error due to modelling the shape of earth but indeed it seems to me a way for solution would be useful so I' ve posted it. What do you mean exactly when you say "if they are far away"?

Comment: See my comment on the question about UTM and Great Circles. The 1000 km estimate is for UTM, and only for certain latitudes, of course, but the errors for UTM are published; NED is relatively unknown.